# SQL query to count the number of records in a time range?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sequence

Suppose you have a table with an user id and date+time (for simplicity in steps of 1 hour)

The table here is ordered by agent and time stamp.

```
Usr Date                Comment
1   2022-11-29 12:00    <- Start of a sequence  
1   2022-11-29 13:00
1   2022-11-29 14:00
1   2022-11-30 12:00    <- Start of a sequence
1   2022-11-30 16:00    <- Start of a sequence
2   2022-11-29 22:00    <- Start of a sequence
2   2022-11-29 23:00
2   2022-11-30 00:00    <- Start of a sequence 
2   2022-11-30 01:00    
3   2022-11-29 13:00    <- Start of a sequence 
3   2022-11-29 14:00
3   2022-11-30 12:00    <- Start of a sequence
3   2022-11-30 13:00
3   2022-11-30 14:00    
4   2022-11-30 12:00    <- Start of a sequence
4   2022-11-30 13:00
4   2022-11-30 14:00
5   2022-11-30 16:00    <- Start of a sequence
```

1. Expected result is the start of a sequence and its length.
2. For simplicity each gap is 1 hour.
3. The start of a new day (00:00) always starts a new sequence

```
Usr Date                Length
1   2022-11-29 12:00    3
1   2022-11-30 12:00    1
1   2022-11-30 16:00    1
2   2022-11-29 22:00    2
2   2022-11-30 00:00    2
3   2022-11-29 13:00    2
3   2022-11-30 12:00    3
4   2022-11-30 12:00    3
5   2022-11-30 16:00    1
```

I found some code samples with `dense_rank` and `row_number` but didn't got a result that was expected.

I have a solution running over each record in the source table and and creating the result table, but it is slow.

The query has to run on a SQL 2012 or later.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has many solutions. It is a question of the required query performance.
I would recommend to calculate the duration at the moment of recording, if there is a question of speed.

Example of a query that returns the required result:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.test;

CREATE TABLE dbo.test
(
  Usr INT, [Date] DATETIME);

DECLARE @gap INT = 1;

INSERT INTO dbo.test (Usr, [Date])
VALUES (1, '2022-11-29T12:00:00')
     , (1, '2022-11-29T13:00:00')
     , (1, '2022-11-29T14:00:00')
     , (1, '2022-11-30T12:00:00')
     , (1, '2022-11-30T16:00:00')
     , (2, '2022-11-29T22:00:00')
     , (2, '2022-11-29T23:00:00')
     , (2, '2022-11-30T00:00:00')
     , (2, '2022-11-30T01:00:00')
     , (3, '2022-11-29T13:00:00')
     , (3, '2022-11-29T14:00:00')
     , (3, '2022-11-30T12:00:00')
     , (3, '2022-11-30T13:00:00')
     , (3, '2022-11-30T14:00:00')
     , (4, '2022-11-30T12:00:00')
     , (4, '2022-11-30T13:00:00')
     , (4, '2022-11-30T14:00:00')
     , (5, '2022-11-30T16:00:00');

WITH lag_cte AS
(
SELECT *
     , LAG([Date], 1, [Date]) OVER (PARTITION BY Usr, CAST([Date] AS DATE) ORDER BY [Date]) lead_date --previous time by usr and date
     , DATEADD(HOUR, -@gap, [Date]) gap_date --calc same group time for comprassion
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Usr, [Date]) rn --sort of identity
  FROM dbo.test
)
SELECT lc.Usr
     , MIN(lc.[Date]) AS [date]
     , COUNT(1) AS [length]
  FROM lag_cte lc
  OUTER APPLY (--previous start of sequence
               SELECT TOP 1 rn AS grouping_rn
                 FROM lag_cte li
               WHERE li.Usr = lc.Usr
                 AND li.[Date] <= lc.[Date]
                 AND li.lead_date != li.gap_date --sequence staert marker
               ORDER BY li.[Date] DESC
              ) g
GROUP BY lc.usr, CAST(lc.[Date] AS DATE), g.grouping_rn
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Arzanis mentioned, there are many solutions that provide the desired result.  The example below should perform reasonably well with a composite primary key on `Usr` and `Date`.

```
WITH time_sequences AS (
    SELECT 
         Usr
        ,Date
        ,LAG(Usr) OVER(PARTITION BY Usr ORDER BY Date) AS PrevUsr
        ,LAG(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Usr ORDER BY Date) AS PrevDate
        ,LEAD(Usr) OVER(PARTITION BY Usr ORDER BY Date) AS NextUsr
        ,LEAD(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Usr ORDER BY Date) AS NextDate
    FROM dbo.test
)
,start_sequences AS (
    SELECT
         Usr
        ,Date
        ,'start' AS comment
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Usr ORDER BY Date) AS seq
    FROM time_sequences
    WHERE PrevUsr IS NULL OR PrevDate <> DATEADD(hour, -1, Date) OR CAST(Date AS date) <> CAST(PrevDate AS date)
)
,end_sequences AS (
    SELECT
         Usr
        ,Date
        ,'end' AS comment
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Usr ORDER BY Date) AS seq
    FROM time_sequences
    WHERE NextUsr IS NULL OR NextDate <> DATEADD(hour, 1, Date) OR CAST(Date AS date) <> CAST(NextDate AS date)
)
SELECT ss.Usr, ss.Date, DATEDIFF(hour, ss.Date, es.Date) + 1 AS SeqLength
FROM start_sequences AS ss
JOIN end_sequences AS es ON es.Usr = ss.Usr AND es.seq = ss.seq
ORDER BY 
      es.Usr
    , es.Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   Usr     INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,Date    DATEtime  NOT NULL
  ,Comment VARCHAR(100) 
);
INSERT INTO mytable(Usr,Date,Comment) VALUES 
(1,'2022-11-29 12:00','<- Start of a sequence'),
(1,'2022-11-29 13:00',NULL),
(1,'2022-11-29 14:00',NULL),
(1,'2022-11-30 12:00','<- Start of a sequence'),
(1,'2022-11-30 16:00','<- Start of a sequence'),
(2,'2022-11-29 22:00','<- Start of a sequence'),
(2,'2022-11-29 23:00',NULL),
(2,'2022-11-30 00:00','<- Start of a sequence'),
(2,'2022-11-30 01:00',NULL),
(3,'2022-11-29 13:00','<- Start of a sequence'),
(3,'2022-11-29 14:00',NULL),
(3,'2022-11-30 12:00','<- Start of a sequence'),
(3,'2022-11-30 13:00',NULL),
(3,'2022-11-30 14:00',NULL),
(4,'2022-11-30 12:00','<- Start of a sequence'),
(4,'2022-11-30 13:00',NULL),
(4,'2022-11-30 14:00',NULL),
(5,'2022-11-30 16:00','<- Start of a sequence');
```

your query

```
select usr,
       comment,
      count(comment) Length
  From (
SELECT
    usr
    ,CASE 
        WHEN Comment IS NULL THEN (
            SELECT TOP 1
                cast(inner_table.Date as varchar(100))
            FROM
                mytable as inner_table
            WHERE
                    inner_table.Usr = mytable.Usr
                AND inner_table.Date < mytable.Date
                AND inner_table.Comment IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY
                inner_table.Date DESC
        )
    ELSE
        Date
    END as Comment
FROM
    mytable) a
group by usr,comment
order by usr,comment
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YCrSFAM2)